# Scrollable div inside container without known height

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to scroll items within a container without known height. I have div `itemsHolder` which fills up the rest of `wrapper` container. `wrapper` container can have any height but contains `header` container which has fixed height. So I don't know the height of `itemsHolder` and I need div `items` to be scrollable. Here's the code I tried but was unsuccessful.

To sum up. There's `wrapper` container containing `header` and `itemsHolder`. `wrapper` has variable height, `header` has fixed height and `itemsHolder` fills the rest of `wrapper` (`wrapper.height - header.height = itemsHolder.height`). I need div `items` to be scrollable within `itemsHolder` without using JS.

Thanks.

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="header">
        title
    </div>
    <div class="itemsHolder">
        <div class="items">
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
            <div class="item">text</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;   
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #00ffff;
}
.items {
    background: #ff00ff;
}
.itemsHolder {
    overflow: scroll;
}
.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B2XUL/

**Update:** I don't know the size of `wrapper`, it may be different each time and therefore I don't know the height of `itemsHolder` so I can't set it fixed.

Comment: Add height:100%; to .itemsHolder?

Comment: It makes the size of scrollbar wrong - too large

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do the following:**

```
.wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;   
    width: 100px;
}

.itemsHolder {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    background: #ccc;
}
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B2XUL/17/)

Comment: If I scroll to the bottom, the scrollbar bypasses to bottom of the div

Answer (score 1):

Set the height of itemsHolder and it will add the scroll if necessary

```
.itemsHolder {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 150px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/B2XUL/4/

**EDIT:** I'm very sorry I can't provide an explanation as to why, but adding bottom padding to `.wrapper` and setting the height of `.itemsHolder` seems to work. You may have to reduce size of wrapper by `35px` when it is set. 
Any explanation for this or even a better fix would be welcomed.

```
.wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;   
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding-bottom: 35px;
}
.itemsHolder {
    overflow: scroll;
    height: 100%;
}
```

(also `.items` seems redundant?)

[see updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2XUL/14/)

Comment: I tried to empathize that I will never know the size of `wrapper` and therefore `itemsHolder` not as well but probably wasn't clear enough. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 0):

Add overflow auto:

```
.wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;   
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
    height: 20%;
    background: #00ffff;
}
.items {
    background: #ff00ff;
}
.itemsHolder {
    height: 80%;
    overflow: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
```

Add overflow-x: hidden if you only want vertical scroll.

[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/B2XUL/7/)

Comment: But well now I see that you have added max-height too :(. The problem is that I don't know the height of it. Going to update my Question.

Comment: Whoa. Forgot to update the FIddle. Had height set to 100%. Updated the fiddle :)

Comment: There's the same issue as with the others – the scrollbar is higher than the div actually, see [Imgur](http://i.imgur.com/KeIhEZf.png)

Comment: Saw that now :(
If you would be ok with it you COULD set the headers height to 20% and the div to 80% (i Hide scroll-x). See this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/B2XUL/9/

Comment: It won't work, the problem is that the height ratios or sizes of divs are unknown to me, they're dynamic. But thank you anyway.

Comment: Dynamic: Hence 20% AND 80% They WILL adjust :)

Comment: But once it can be 30% and 70%, next time 10% and 90% etc.

Answer (score 0):

Using calc() CSS property, you can achieve `wrapper.height - header.height = itemsHolder.height`

```
.itemsHolder {
overflow: auto;
height:calc(100% - 50px);
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about calc() support yet. Thank you anyway

Comment: IE9+ and all the major browsers will support.

Comment: But what about android <4.4 for example

Answer (score 0):

[js fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/B2XUL/13/)

```
.wrapper {
    background: #ccc;
    height: 200px;   
    width: 100px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.header {
    height: 50px;
    background: #00ffff;
}
.items {
    background: #ff00ff;

}
.itemsHolder {
    max-height: 150px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
.item {
    width: 100px;
    height: 80px;
    float: left;
}
```

[image]

Comment: I can't set height of itemsholder as I dont know it. See updated answer and my replies here. Thank you.